# Send SMS using Arduino

Tags: c, arduino, gsm

I am currently working on a project. I tried different sample testing code to send sms to my current number but it won't sent any.

1. Should my SIM 800L GSM module sim and my phone number have the same carrier?
2. I even followed the other people's advices on using a 3.7v power supply.
3. Library already included.
4. Correct RX-TX TX-RX, VCC, RST pins.

Below is a sample code from what I have been following.

```
#include <Sim800l.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> //is necesary for the library!! 
Sim800l Sim800l;  //to declare the library
char* text;
char* number;
bool error; //to catch the response of sendSms


void setup(){
  Sim800l.begin(); // initializate the library. 
  text="Testing Sms";  //text for the message. 
  number="2926451386"; //change to a valid number.
  error=Sim800l.sendSms(number,text);
  // OR 
  //Sim800l.sendSms("+540111111111","the text go here")


}

void loop(){
  //do nothing
}
```

This should be sending a text message to a phone number but I am not receiving any.

Comment: Did you mean to tag this as `c` rather than `c#`?

Comment: Make sure, that you have correct SIM card. In many countries GPRS traffic is restricted for corporate parties only.

Comment: The issue can be do different problems 1) You software is not communicating with the Modem 2) The Modem isn't sending to the cell tower.  I would first see if the Modem came with any software to send messages and test if message work to your cell phone.  The carrier should make a difference because any cell phone sending a SMS should be received on any other cell phone. All carriers are connected.  The real question is the Modem connected a carrier.

Comment: Could you please do a `Serial.println(error);`, to see if there is a error when he try send a message?

Comment: I tried putting Serial.println(error); but the serial monitor is not displaying error.

Comment: I also tried different testing code like using FONA library. As displayed on my Serial Monitor, it says "No response to AT...". And I cannot seem to find the problem.

Comment: Did you taked your example from [here](https://github.com/cristiansteib/Sim800l/blob/master/examples/sendSms/sendSms.ino) right? Maybe the power supply it's wrong and your TX and RX could be wrong, you must connect into pins *10* and *11*

Comment: @EsdrasXavier RX-TX 10, TX-RX 11.connected already. I am currently using MEGA 2560. I have a 3.7v power supply.

Yes. I took from that example.

Comment: If you take a look at [README](https://github.com/cristiansteib/Sim800l/blob/master/README.md), is said you must use **(3.8v)~(4.4v)!**, and you are using 3.7v. Can you use 5V with some resistor into your Sim800I?

Comment: @EsdrasXavier Can we possibly use a (3) Double AA batteries with 1.5v each? I also asked on different groups and they have recommended a 3.7v power supply but it won't work, as you said that I will be needing a 5V battery.

Comment: Yes you can... Take a look at [this site](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-power-a-project/all), you will be able to understand how to use it

Comment: @EsdrasXavier Thank you sir.

Comment: Just to test if your modem is working fine with your supply. Try connecting it with a serial to usb converter and attach it to your PC. Open a serial terminal in your PC and open the COM port on which your device appeared. Now try sending any simple command, you can find them from here https://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/AT_Commands